# HTML button on ASP.NET user control is posting back

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

Very strange behavior for me. I have two html buttons in my ASP.NET user control who are having onclick event handler attached to it. But it is posting back and I see container page's Load event being hit. But page load of user control itself is not hit. I don't want this postback. It should behave as a html control and should not post back the page.

Please suggest the logic that is causing it to postback and that to only at container page level not its own page_load. Also please tell me how to avoid such behavior.

> UserControl Code

```
<%@ Implements Interface="System.Web.UI.ICallbackEventHandler" %>

<input type="button" id="btnMarkAll" value="MarkAll" onclick="CallServer('Mark', ''); return false;" />

                <input type="button" id="btnUnMarkAll" value="UnMarkAll" onclick="CallServer('UnMark', '');" />

function ReceiveServerData(arg, context) {}


ClientScriptManager cm = Page.ClientScript;
        string cbReference = cm.GetCallbackEventReference(this, "arg", "ReceiveServerData", "");
        string callBackScript = "function CallServer(arg, context) {" + cbReference + ";}";
        cm.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "CallServer", callBackScript, true);

public void RaiseCallbackEvent(String eventArgument){}

public string GetCallbackResult()
    {
        return strReturn;
    }
```

It seems callback is not registered properly.

I kept debugger on page load event of the container aspx page and raisecallbackevent function. Strangely when I click UnMark button, which is an HTML control, the page load event debugger is hit but raisecallbackevent debugger not hit.

First of all why PageLoad event hit and secondly why RaiseCallBackEvent debugger not hit.

Comment: Even if I return false after calling function CallServer(), then also PageLoad event of container ASPX page is called. Please provide some help!!

Comment: I removed CallBack and implemented AJAX callback to a static webmethod using JQuery. After that webmethod is called, pageload event of the page also gets called, Why?? I am fully confused in the concept.